# Releasing instance if service not enabled?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-location

I would just like to check if I have this right, I am creating an instance of `CCLocationManager` and then checking if location services are enabled. If it is not enabled I then report an error, release the instance and carry on, does that look/sound right?

```
locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
BOOL supportsService = [locationManager locationServicesEnabled];

if(supportsService) {
    [locationManager setDelegate:self];
    [locationManager setDistanceFilter:kCLDistanceFilterNone];
    [locationManager setDesiredAccuracy:kCLLocationAccuracyBest];
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
} else {
    NSLog(@"Location services not enabled.");
    [locationManager release];
}
... 
...
... more code
```

cheers gary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To prevent errors further down you could set `locationManager` to nil after releasing. Other than that there's no problem with your approach.